# Accessing Properties of items contained in an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, ienumerable

Sorry if the title is misleading, you can correct if you have an idea what I'm trying to say. 
I have a function which takes in an IEnumberable. The IEnumerable is type annonymous.
My Function is below

```
public void AddToCollection_Short(IEnumerable query)
{
    List<object> list = new List<object>();
    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        var obj = new object();
        var date = item.Date.ToShortDateString();
        obj = new { date, item.Id, item.Subject };
        list.Add(obj);
    }
    AllQueries = list;
    OnPropertyChanged("AllQueries");
}
```

It doesn't recognize the suffix such as .Id, .Date, .Subject. May I ask what approach I should take to fix this. Is there something like `IEnumerable<Datetime Date, int Id, string Subject>` query

Comment: How is the object you are passing in as `query` defined?

Comment: Such a method should not be public.  The fields of an anonymous type are not accessible in another assembly.  Only using *internal* makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use (in C# 4.0 and higher) the `dynamic` keyword or update the signature to `AddToCollection_Short`.

```
public void AddToCollection_Short(IEnumerable query)
{
    List<object> list = new List<object>();
    foreach (dynamic item in query)
    {
        var obj = new object();
        var date = item.Date.ToShortDateString();
        obj = new { date, item.Id, item.Subject };
        list.Add(obj);
    }
    AllQueries = list;
    OnPropertyChanged("AllQueries");
}
```

Comment: I have Version 4.0 and It doesnt recognize the suffixes still

Comment: Maybe it was introduce in 4.5?

Comment: @user3276954, `dynamic` isn't going to give you intellisense, so you're not getting your "suffixes" (or property names) in the IDE. `dynamic` is a way for you to tell the compiler to effectively ignore this piece of the code until runtime. If you want intellisense on those objects, your method needs to be more strongly typed to the class or interface of the object in the IEnumerable, such as `IEnumerable<Foo>`, where Foo is the class (including base class) or interface of the items in your query.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the type, you can cast your objects

```
 foreach (var item in query.Cast<YourType>())
```

If  you don't know then you can use *dynamic* feature.And you can access your properties without a compile time error but if you try to access a property or a method which is not exist you will get a `RuntimeBinderException` in runtime.

```
foreach (dynamic item in query)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to specify a type parameter to your method.

```
public void AddToCollection_Short<T>(IEnumerable<T> query) where T : IAmCommonInterface
{
    List<object> list = new List<object>();
    foreach (T item in query)
    {
        var obj = new object();
        var date = item.Date.ToShortDateString();
        obj = new { date, item.Id, item.Subject };
        list.Add(obj);
    }
    AllQueries = list;
    OnPropertyChanged("AllQueries");
}
```

and your common interface for your type paramater would have all the properties that you want on it.
The advantage to this is the compiler will tell you when you try to use this on an Enumerable that doesn't have those properties.